# Expanding boost preprocessor sequence to std::tuple

Tags: c++, boost, macros

If I have a boost preprocessor sequence macro like:

```
#define BOOST_PP_SEQUENCE\
    (float)\
    (int)\
    (bool)\
```

Is it possible to convert this tuple into a std::tuple? I would like to convert this into something like:

```
using RealTuple = ...  //resulting in std::tuple<float, int, bool>
```

Comment: It is not a tuple, it is a [sequence](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/data/sequences.html).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was:

```
using Tuple = std::tuple<BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQUENCE)>;
```